# JPA i18n issue with mapping columns

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a project, where some of the data are stored in multiple languages. For persistence I use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate. My model is the following:

I have an embeddable class for storing a string in a given locale:

```
@Embeddable
public class MultilingualData {

    @Column(name = "locale", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = LocaleConverter.class)
    private Locale locale;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
}
```

And I also have a class, where I want to use that MultilingualData as a value of a Map, and the Locale in the MultilingualData as key for a better processing.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "multilingual_string")
public class MultilingualString extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2434353448112062292L;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "locale", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "multilingual_string_map",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "string_id"))
    private Map<Locale, MultilingualData> localizedStrings;
```

A class where I use the MultilingualString:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "name")
    private MultilingualString name;
```

So when JPA generates the tables, in the 'multilingual_string_map' two columns are generated for the locale itself. One with the name 'locale', as given in the model, and it creates another one with 'localized_strings_key' as part of the primary key. So when I store a multilingual data, the locale is saved twice.

I want to get rid of that extra column, because it is redundant. I know I did not configured the mapping right, so I hope someone can fix my mistake here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you define the join column as `insertable = false`? Is the map never going to be populated from within your code?

In any case, `@MapKeyJoinColumn` is only used when the map key is an entity. `@MapKeyColumn` is what you want.

(the fact that `@MapKeyColumn` is missing from your model means Hibernate was forced to use a default name for the key column i.e. `localized_strings_key`. The fact that the `locale` column also got created despite the map key not being an entity is, well, undocumented behaviour)